# Android Read Result From MySQL

Tags: android

My code used to work, it does not work anymore, I tried troubleshooting and can't figure out why.

I have this piece of code in my PHP:

```
$android_id_01 = $_GET['pmysql_room_id'];
$android_id_02 = "";

$f = fopen("00_android_id_01.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, print_r($android_id_01, true));
fclose($f);  

$f = fopen("00_android_id_02.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, print_r($android_id_02, true));
fclose($f);
```

For troubleshooting I created two android IDs ($android_id_01 and $android_id_02) which are both empty (The first one is From Android and the second one I created directly from PHP).

Now when I launch my Android device, the PHP file is executed from server side and both the text files are created empty and identical. Now my code only works when I use `$android_id_02` and not `$android_id_01` from the code below:

```
if ($android_id == '')
{
     //my code
}
```

(Yes when I use either one of the $android_id_01 OR $android_id_02 I rename it to $android_id and comment out the other one)

My question is, although this was working yesterday, why does it work with `$android_id_02 = "";` and not `$android_id_01 = $_GET['pmysql_room_id'];` even though they are both empty????

I don't know what changed from yesterday to today.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of troubleshooting I found a solution, strange though.

On the server side "display_errors" under PHP settings must be turned off. Somehow having this on interferes with the json_encode sent back to android client. (even though my code is not generating any errors)